# multiple MATCH() AGAINST() in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, match-against

Please be informed that I couldn't find anything about this specific problem on google.

As `AGAINST()` can take only `single string` literal,I need to run multiple `MATCH() AGAINST` in a query,like this

```
 SELECT * FROM `user`.`user_det` WHERE MATCH(busi_title,category) AGAINST('$search_term') AND MATCH(country) AGAINST('$country')
```

But this `query` is not working.How can I make this query to work?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Mysql FULLTEXT capabilities are a bit rudimentary,you might want to use sphinx which stands between the user and mysql,very feature rich.http://sphinxsearch.com/

Comment: @Mihai I'm using `Sphinx` for my website already.But for only one part of my code I need to use `Match() Against()`,as I can't use `Sphinx` on that case for some reason.

Comment: Are you setup FULLTEXT index on bussi_title, category and country?

Comment: MySQL can handle a single `MATCH...AGAINST`, but struggle with a second one.  Can't you do `country = '$country'` ??